# Separating cell boundaries in the following image and also do nuclear counting using python

Tags: python, image, image-segmentation

I tried to use watershed with Otsu for thresholding but its only picking up nuclear boundaries,I want to  segment cells boundaries

I used Otsu followed by noise removal with opening ,identifying sure background, applying distance transform, using it to define sure foreground, defining unknown, creating markers[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("images/bio_watershed/Osteosarcoma_01.tif")

cells=img[:,:,0]  
#Threshold image to binary using OTSU. ALl thresholded pixels will be set 
#to 255

ret1, thresh = cv2.threshold(cells, 0, 255, 
cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)



# Morphological operations to remove small noise - opening

 kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
 opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel, 
 iterations = 2)

 # finding sure background

 sure_bg = cv2.dilate(opening,kernel,iterations=10)
 #applying dustance transform

 dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening,cv2.DIST_L2,5)

 ret2, sure_fg 
 =cv2.threshold(dist_transform,0.5*dist_transform.max(),255,0)


 # Unknown region 
 sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg)
 unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg,sure_fg)

 #Now we create a marker and label the regions inside. 

 ret3, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg)


 #add 10 to all labels so that sure background is not 0, but 10

 markers = markers+10

 # Now, mark the region of unknown with zero

 markers[unknown==255] = 0

 #applying watershed 

 markers = cv2.watershed(img,markers)

 # color boundaries in yellow. 

 img[markers == -1] = [0,255,255]  

 img2 = color.label2rgb(markers, bg_label=0)

 cv2.imshow('Overlay on original image', img)
 cv2.imshow('Colored Cells', img2)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
```

by running this code I get following nuclear boundary segmentation but I want to get the cell boundaries
[image: nuclear segmentation]

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Have you some code already? Does it end to an error or unexpected result? If not, look for some tutorials how to get started and return here when you have StackOverflow -suitable problem. See guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Yes i wrote the code, as i mentioned above I only get nuclear segmentation, only nuclear boundaries but not cell boundaries

Comment: In that case include code example in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are still looking for an answer but I have edited your code to segment the cell boundaries. You need to select the image slice that shows the actin filaments, which is in index 1.

I have also used an edge detector followed by contour drawing to outline the cell boundaries.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.io as skio

img = cv2.imread("cells.png")

img_read = img[:,:,1] #Shows the actin filaments

#Denoising
img_denoise = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(img_read, 45, 7, 35)

#Canny edge detector
img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_denoise, 10, 200)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(2,2))
img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations = 2)

#Contour finding
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img_dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
img_med = cv2.cvtColor(img_denoise, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
img_final = cv2.drawContours(img_med, contours, -1, (0,128,128), 2, 4)

skio.imsave("img_output.tif", img_final)

cv2.imshow('Overlay on original image', img_final)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but this is just outlining a mass of cells, what i need is separating the boundaries of each cell , to explain more clearly each nucleus occupies one cell, so i need those boundaries

Answer (score 0):

The example you have is good for color-based segmentation as it is (better resolution will improve the result though).

Contrast is good enough (and can be improved), so did a very quick test without using OpenCV (so no code to share).

Nuclear boundary:
[image]

Cell boundary:
[image]

Combined:
[image]

Or as a separate masks:
[image]

So I'd say it is all about [delta E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) and proper segmentation.